# collapse: Modifying Columns by row along with combine values from multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, aggregate, tidytable

I want to translate the following `R` code using [tidytable](https://markfairbanks.github.io/tidytable/) into [collapse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collapse/index.html): **Advanced and Fast Data Transformation**.

**tidytable Code**

```
library(tidytable)
library(collapse)
Out1 <- 
  wlddev %>% 
  mutate_rowwise.(New1 = sum(c_across.(PCGDP:GINI), na.rm = TRUE))
Out1 %>% 
  select.(New1)
# A tidytable: 13,176 x 1
    New1
   <dbl>
 1  32.4
 2  33.0
 3  33.5
 4  34.0
 5  34.5
 6  34.9
 7  35.4
 8  35.9
 9  36.4
10  36.9
# ... with 13,166 more rows
```

**collapse Code**

```
library(collapse)
Out2 <- 
  wlddev %>% 
  ftransform(New1 = fsum(across(PCGDP:GINI), na.rm = TRUE))

  Error in `context_peek()`:
  ! `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any hint please.

Comment: Why tag [tag:data.table] if you're specifically asking for [tag:tidytable] and [tag:collapse]? (FYI, the [tag:collapse] collapse self-declares that it *"deprecated and should not be used"* due to its ambiguity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder why you need to come up with something so complex. You have functions like `rowSums` in base R, and you have parallel statistical functions in `kit`:

```r
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
library(kit, include.only = "psum")  
library(microbenchmark)
  
microbenchmark(
A = wlddev %>%
  ftransform(New1 = rowSums(qM(slt(., PCGDP:GINI)), na.rm = TRUE)),
B = wlddev %>%
  ftransform(New1 = psum(slt(., PCGDP:GINI), na.rm = TRUE)), 
C = wlddev %>%
  ftransform(New1 = psum(PCGDP, LIFEEX, GINI, na.rm = TRUE))
)

#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr   min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>     A 68.88 97.8875 194.24037 102.2335 113.8775 4646.366   100
#>     B 25.83 30.1350  35.43548  34.9115  38.6630   56.416   100
#>     C 22.55 25.8095  29.99396  30.5860  32.9025   53.792   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The `?fsum` from `collapse` does columnwise sum

> fsum is a generic function that computes the (column-wise) sum of all values in x, (optionally) grouped by g and/or weighted by w (e.g. to calculate survey totals).

Based on the `tidytable` code, it is `rowwise`, so one option is to select (`slt`) the columns of interest, `t`ranspose, convert to `tibble/data.frame` and use `fsum` and create a new column

```
library(collapse)
Out2 <- wlddev %>%
    slt(PCGDP:GINI) %>%
    t %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    fsum(.) %>% 
    ftransform(wlddev, New1 = .)
```

---

`sum` returns 0 when all the elements are `NA` whereas `fsum` by default uses `na.rm = TRUE` and it returns NA if all the elements are `NA`

```
> fsum(c(NA, NA))
[1] NA
> sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0
```

Therefore, if we change the `NA` to 0 in the second data, the output will be the same as OP's 'Out1'

```
> Out2$New1[is.na(Out2$New1)] <- 0
> all.equal(Out1, Out2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking lead from @akrun answer, I came up with a solution with more speed.

```
Out3 <- 
  wlddev %>%
  slt(PCGDP:GINI) %>%
  qDT() %>% 
  t %>%
  fsum(.) %>% 
  ftransform(.data = wlddev, New1 = .) %>%
  qDT() %>% 
  replace_NA(X = ., value = 0, cols = "New1")
```

**Speed Comparison**

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  Out1 = 
    wlddev %>% 
    mutate_rowwise.(New1 = sum(c_across.(PCGDP:GINI), na.rm = TRUE))
, Out2 =
    wlddev %>%
    slt(PCGDP:GINI) %>%
    t %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    fsum(.) %>% 
    ftransform(wlddev, New1 = .)
, Out3 = 
    wlddev %>%
    slt(PCGDP:GINI) %>%
    qDT() %>% 
    t %>%
    fsum(.) %>% 
    ftransform(.data = wlddev, New1 = .) %>%
    qDT() %>% 
    replace_NA(X = ., value = 0, cols = "New1")
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 Out1 72618.0 78268.75 81296.992 79888.50 81671.10 162397.8   100
 Out2 33549.7 35520.75 37763.537 37728.25 39021.90  55001.3   100
 Out3   241.2   310.85   360.225   357.40   387.35    780.1   100
```